# awk: Extracting a fixed number of rows where the last row number may vary

Tags: text-processing, awk

This question may look like a duplicate, but only at first glance.
Of course, I would no longer need help in how to code a one-liner that extracts a fixed number of **continuous** lines (e. g. 5 in this example) from a data source, e. g. `top`:

```
$ top -b -n1 | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%23s %7s\n","cpu","mem"} NR==8,NR==12 {printf "%-16s %6s%% %6s%%\n",$12,$9,$10}'
```

This is even a very handy one-liner that will show the processes in the system that take most CPU, with the memory usage being printed in an additional column.

So far, so good ... however, it's not *that* trivial.  To get this list, `top` is necessary and may (on low system load) show up *itself* as process in this list. I'd rather not want that, since these calls are done in **intervals** and would regularly spawn `top` (if only for a short while).
It is known that we want to begin at **line 8** (NR==8). However, what if a second `top` in another virtual desktop was forgotten about in a terminal which messes up the list as well? In this case, two `top` processes must be omitted, so the last line to process will be 14.

So to improve this output and to filter out every `top` line that is in there, a counter seems mandatory (perhaps a `for` loop that we exit with a `break`?).
Unfortunately my attempts with a for loop and `i = <number>` have been fruitless so far, because it would rather print every line as many times as `i` indicates.

I've come up with a rather hackish solution, which works but may be unsuitable for more complex cases:

```
top -b -n1 | grep -v ' \btop\b$' | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%23s %7s\n","cpu","mem"} NR==8,NR==12 {printf "%-16s %6s%% %6s%%\n",$12,$9,$10}'
```

*(Note: This may give unwanted results if the user name in the second column happens to be "top" as well)*

Anyways, could I get a clue how to do that in `awk` please (and get rid of the `grep`)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This is not answering your question,
but it solves the problem you are trying to solve, in a completely different way:

The full command is this (see below for example output):

```
ps -o comm,%cpu,%mem --sort -%cpu -A | head -6
```

I will describe the parts of it:

- using `ps` to have more control about the output
- Printing only the three columns we need with `-o comm,%cpu,%mem`
- Make `ps` sort the data internally `--sort -%cpu`, by CPU, reverse.
- List all processes with `-A`
- Show the header and the first 5 lines of the result by `| head -6`

The output is similar to the output of your first command:

```
$ ps -o comm,%cpu,%mem --sort -%cpu -A | head -6
COMMAND         %CPU %MEM
firefox          8.9 15.5
Xorg             1.3  5.6
parcellite       0.3  1.6
compiz           0.2  1.8
konsole          0.1  0.9
```

The process `ps` is listed in the full list - one could exclude it based on the parent PID.

If we want to exclude `top` processes elsewhere, we can do that based on the command name.

The `-A` selecting all processes would be replaced by `-N ...`:

```
ps ... -N --ppid $$ -C top
```

As we now need to exclude processes, we use `-N` to select all others processes than the ones we match.

To exclude `ps`, we use that it has the current interactive shell as parent process, so it will have the parent pid, PPID of the shell. The PID of the current shell is `$$`.
So `--ppid $$` matches all child processes of the current shell, and we know that there will be only one, `ps`.

We want to also exclude the `top` processes that may run on other displays on the same machine. We do that by matching the command name with `-C top`.

The full command with excluding the `ps` process itself (and only this) and all `top` processes would be:

```
ps -o comm,%cpu,%mem --sort -%cpu -N --ppid $$ -C top | head -6
```

Comment: Very nice alternate solution as well, thanks! Might even take less resources than the `top` approach.

Comment: Yeah; I answered the question that was asked, but I was silently wondering whether `top` was really the best way to get a one-time list of process information.

Comment: Oh, it will take much less ressources of course. Should be near optimal.

Comment: @G-Man Well, `top` displays the stuff pre-sorted already, whilst with `ps` you'd *normally* have to pipe a `sort` to the line to achieve the same. Unless you know about the `--sort` option in `ps`, which I had ignored...

Answer (score 5):

```
top command | awk 'BEGIN { print header; count=5}
                   NR>=8 { if ($0 ~ /your top regex/) next;
                           print fields; if (--count == 0) exit}'
```

On every line starting with #8, if it matches `top`, ignore it.
Otherwise, print the portion of it that you want.
The fifth time you print a line (that doesn’t match `top`), exit.

Comment: Please stop italicising parts of your code: it makes (what is otherwise a helpful contribution) quite difficult to read.

Comment: Really? You have difficulty reading italics? I'm using the convention of millions of computer manuals: things that you type literally (e.g., "if" and "next") are plain text; things that you replace with your own value (e.g., regex and fields) are italic.

Comment: Thank you! That might already be the solution. And I have nothing against your italics, for it leaves those who ask a little chance to think themselves. :) I'd always just need these general ideas, not everything word-by-word. BTW, about the `count=5` bit: very sneaky! I was trying so hard with `for` loops, but got nowhere (except for silly output as well as annoying and totally confusing error messages from `awk`)

Comment: @G-Man I see no issue with italics in itsef - the distracting aspect is that it is inconsistent with other code markup. Would be great to have syntax highlight of this level, including italics, everywhere; The `google-code-prettify` used here claims to support `awk` - but even with setting the language explicitly, I did not get more than highlighting the `awk` code as a quoted string...

Comment: Very nice solution. As an aesthetic preference, in `awk`, I would probably be more inclined to write `NR>=8 && !/top/ { print fields; count--; } !count { exit; }`. I'm not sure if this is considered more idiomatic by professional `awk`ers, but I personally find it so.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't have commented otherwise, would I? As for convention; the SO sites use particular styles for <code> elements, one can only presume that there has been significant UX/design thinking to inform those choices, but if you are convinced that you know better...

Comment: Caveat: Make sure you keep in mind that __a \b in GNU `awk` (gawk) will stand for backspace__, so to work correctly, the regex in my OP must be changed to `/ \ytop\y$/`, with \y` standing for "word boundar __y__". This has just cost me another 15 minutes to figure out, since my regex made `top` keep on spitting out itself all the same, although I was sure I had filtered it out by now....BUT: this is a __GNU-ism__; it's not available in traditional `awk` implementations (neither is `\b`).

Comment: @syntaxerror: ***Thank you!!!*** for justifying my typography convention better than I could. I was hesitant to say `if ($0 ~ / \btop\b$/)` because I wasn’t sure that `/ \btop\b$/` was right, and, since the details of the regex were irrelevant to my answer, I didn’t want to spend time researching it. And I didn’t want to say `if ($0 ~ /your top regex/)` because that’s not the right thing to type. And “angle brackets” (`<` and `>`) are, IMNSHO, grossly overused to designate placeholders like _file_, _value_, _string_ and _number_.

Comment: Speaking of which, some regex engines even *do* use angle brackets for word boundary matching :) (however they won't work in either `awk` or `gawk`) ... Anyways, I think it'll be worth working on a solution that will simulate word boundary on non-GNU `awk`, since the blind following of GNUisms has almost become epidemic on SE/SO, and thus one of my pet peeves as well.